# John Carter Film - Thern Medallion Teleportation

Tags: john-carter, edgar-rice-burroughs, barsoom

In the film *John Carter*, Dejah Thoris is explaining Thern Teleportation to John Carter. I can't remember exactly what she said, but is it in any way similar to what Quantum Teleportation or Biodigital Cloning is ?

Comment: Tip: forget this abomination of a movie exists and just read the books. In the books, the Therns don't teleport; they have secret passages and use tricks and illusions to make it appear as though they can teleport.

Comment: [Quantum Teleportation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_teleportation) doesn't mean what you think it means. Are you asking if this teleportation is kill-and-clone or if it is literal teleportation?

Comment: A little poking around describes it once as "a series of shenanigans" which leads to teleportation.  That's probably about as technical as we are going to get....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The John Carter film was vastly different from the books, so I'll restrict my answer to the movie ONLY. Within the movie, the medallion uses neither traditional teleportation methods NOR biodigital cloning to whisk John away to Mars. Instead, his mind is placed into a physical COPY of his original body while his actual body on Earth remains dormant (and apparently in some kind of biological stasis). As alluded to in the movie, it's like a telegraph - his mind was sent "across the wire" but a separate body exists on each end of the "wire" (just like a piece of paper with the message on it exists at both ends of the telegraph line).

Comment: So, his mind is being sent to a body on Mars? Then how does this new body LOOK like him, and have these "powers" that Martians don't have? Man, I need to watch this again.

Comment: The body on Mars is an exact copy of his original, and was apparently created by the medallion process. The original body would have the powers on Mars (based on differences between Earth & Mars), so the copy does too.

Comment: Then where did the exact copy of his original body come from ?

Comment: @Bubba - We have to assume it was created by the medallion (or rather, it's counterpart on Mars).